# When i use Google Map Api v2 for map then i can't add google play service library

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

**I want to show current location in map using Google Map v2. I create sha key and generate API key and also integrate with androidmanifest.xml. I download example of following link:**

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

**I also give internet permission and other but in my log-cat following error display.**

```
11-20 11:09:59.190: E/dalvikvm(719): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.MainActivity.onLocationChanged
11-20 11:09:59.190: W/dalvikvm(719): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 460 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;) in Lin/wptrafficanalyzer/locationingooglemapv2/MainActivity;
11-20 11:09:59.190: D/dalvikvm(719): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
11-20 11:09:59.220: D/dalvikvm(719): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0cdc at 0x12 in Lin/wptrafficanalyzer/locationingooglemapv2/MainActivity;.onLocationChanged
11-20 11:09:59.482: D/AndroidRuntime(719): Shutting down VM
11-20 11:09:59.482: W/dalvikvm(719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 11 more
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 21 more
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
11-20 11:09:59.501: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 24 more
```

Now what i can do for displaying map?

Comment: Have you add the google play service library...

Comment: yes but it display error when add google play service library.

Comment: i cant add external library in project. what is the reason for that?

Comment: that Google play service library should be in sample directory...      follow the link  https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Comment: i know i already import google play library from following path: android-sdk->extras->google->google_play_services->libproject.

Comment: but when i fetch library using right click on project and goto property and in android section add library but error mark is display.

Comment: with red color cross mark ,ya yes..

Comment: yes right. what is solution for that?

Comment: from sdk-->extras-->google_play_services  copy that folder and paste it where the project you have create in that directory...and then add the library your problem will be solved...

Comment: which folder copy?? means extras or google_play_services?

Comment: google play service copy it and paste it in the where the project is created in directory

Comment: ok now google_play_service library set in my project but when i run my project then map is not loaded and following error display in logcat: "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors)."

Comment: Continue : "The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length.The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included."

Comment: and make sure you have enabled the google map api v2 in Google api console enble it by going to services...

Comment: i already create new project and get api key in google api console using sha fingerprints. but i dont why map is not loaded??

Comment: you enable by goign to services google map v2 if off make it on..

Comment: i already on following services in google api console: Google Maps Android Api V2, Google Maps Coordinate, Google Maps Engine Api, Google Maps Track Api, Places Api.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start   and even try to follow the steps clear which are mentioned in this link....

Comment: and even enable google map android api v2 and v3 also...

Comment: and even u try to clean the project and also restart Ide like eclipse uninstall the app in mobile/emulator run once again..

Comment: @Maneti Vinay: thanx a lot dude for help. i am success for displaying map.

Comment: your are always welcome mann......

Comment: When i use sample code for map display using "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start" link but following error is display in logcat:FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapimpletation/com.example.mapimpletation.MainActivity}:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment." What can i do for that?

Comment: ok fine, which u have provide the link is not working,

Comment: i think you have an error in the xml fine in the res folder clearly check it....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: my xml has following code: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: i just use relative layout in fragment control

Comment: map screen is display in my actual device but map is not load. so what can i do for?

Comment: try to create an api key with your api key and package and paste that api key in androidmanifest.xml..

Comment: @maneti vinay: i got result for build path and re-enter jar file. thanx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maps Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



}
```

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YourPackageName"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="YourPackageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="YourPackageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="YourPackageName.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YourKey" />
    </application>`enter code here`

</manifest>
```

Open sdk manager and download google play service under extras, you will get two libraries google-play-services_lib.jar and google-play-services.jar. You can find these libraries under google play service in extras. You have to copy these two libraries and paste under **lib** folder in your app and also add these libraries under java Build path.

Comment: i already use this code but following error generated: " class: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment could not found.

Comment: When i use sample code for map display using "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start" link but following error is display in logcat:FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapimpletation/com.example.mapimpletation.MainActivity}:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment." What can i do for that?

Comment: i implement your source code now what i take <android:value=" "> instead "4030500" for <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" /> in androidmenifest.xml file?

Comment: i just restart my eclipse and following error display in console :  LocationGoogleMapV2Demo] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
,Versions found are:
,Path: D:\october2013_Workspace\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar
 Length: 380917
  SHA-1: 19584d79c3c85315cbd9227c1b7abe781ab1ae76
 Path: \LocationGoogleMapV2Demo\libs\google-play-services.jar
 Length: 959413,SHA-1: cebe8e4a3a469c4623addcca1dc571407ff3a08e
 Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: map screen is display in my actual device but map is not load. so what can i do for?

Comment: check if you get autogenerated package "com.google.android.gm" under your gen folder in your app and add import google play service library project in your eclipse and then add two libraries google-play-services_lib.jar and google-play-services.jar in your lib folder in your project.

Comment: yes, "com.google.android.gm" is created in gen folder. libraries google-play-services_lib.jar and google-play-services.jar add manually? means copy it and paste in libs folder?

Comment: when i paste google-play-services_lib.jar file from "\...\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar" in libs folder then project contains errors. when i fix project property then don't remove it.

Comment: You may be doing something wrong because this code works for me. Take .apk file from bin folder in zip file send by me and run .apk file in your android device to check that code is working.

Comment: your code is import in eclipse then it contains some error and display project icon with red mark. i checked code manually and open .java file in src folder.

Comment: ok i got your problem,Right click your project > Build path >configure build path > remove google-play-service-libs and google-play-service.jar and add it once again. this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure by going to google api console go to **services** in go down you will find google map v2 eanble it...
[image]
To add a reference to a library project, follow these steps:

```
    1. Make sure that both the project library and the application project that depends on it are in your workspace. If one of the projects is missing, import it into your workspace.
    2. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
    3.In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
    4.Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
    5.From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
    6.When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
    7.Click OK to close the Properties window.
```

how to add reference Google play Library

[Android Library Projects](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)

Comment: Make sure that both the project library and the application project that depends on it are in your workspace. If one of the projects is missing, import it into your workspace.